# How do I run a bash or python script via cron, visible on the local desktop

Tags: bash, lubuntu, python, cron

I have a production server that runs several bash scripts on the local desktop. Two scripts run all the time and don't need to be stopped. I have a third Python script that I need to start at 9AM. It automatically quits at 1:30AM.

If I add the following to my cron file, it successfully launches leafpad.

```
* * * * * env DISPLAY=:0 leafpad
```

As an example, this doesn't work:

```
* * * * * env DISPLAY=:0 /bin/bash
```

I tried

```
* * * * * env DISPLAY=:0 /usr/bin/python /scripts/mypython.py
```

and the script does start (it sends a startup email), but it's not running on the desktop. What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`leafpad` has a GUI, `/bin/bash` and `/usr/bin/python` not. You need a terminal emulator, eg `lxterm`.

```
* * * * * env DISPLAY=:0 lxterm -e "/bin/bash -c '/usr/bin/python /scripts/mypython.py'"
```

or a bash:

```
* * * * * env DISPLAY=:0 lxterm -e "/bin/bash"
```

Comment: This didn't work for me.

Comment: Which terminal do you use? `lxterm`?

Comment: I use bash. Is that not the terminal? Whatever Ctrl+Alt+T launches is what I use.

Comment: `bash` is a shell, `lxterminal` is a terminal emulator. You can start a shell inside a terminal.

Comment: Okay. I'll keep toying with it.

Comment: This worked: `* * * * * env DISPLAY=:0 lxterm -e "/bin/bash -c '/usr/bin/python /scripts/mypython.py'"`

Modify your initial answer and I'll accept it as the answer.